# StructureMap equivalent of CastleWindsor container.Release() method

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, structuremap

I am trying to manually release an instance created by StructureMap. In CastleWindsor it is possible to do this:

```
private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

public void GetInstanceThenRelease(Type myType)
{
    var instance = (myType)this._container.Resolve(myType);
    this._container.Release(instance);
}
```

How would I achieve this in StructureMap?

Comment: You don't have to. StructureMap does not track your instances.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve is to do with a WebAPI ActionFilter out-living the controller it is decorating. I have configured structureMap to 'BuildUp' the properties of the action filter, but because the action filter is still around its injected dependencies are too. For that reason I'd like to 'Release' those injected dependencies manually.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, ActionFilters are typically singletons (created once by Web API). This makes them not a good candidate for Dependency Injection, unlesss all its dependencies (and their dependencies) are singletons too, which is quite unlikely. Releasing those dependendies does not work, since 'releasing' them does not remove them from the ActionFilter and they are still referenced. Further more, replacing them will result in concurrency issues, since the ActionFilter is reused by threads. I think you should try a different approach.

Comment: Steven - your first comment should be an answer, and accepted as correct.